# Ruby gui Scribble - How to get it

Tags: ruby, scribble

I read the article below and would like to try scribble in Ruby but the only source i can find is on svn which i don't have or use.

Here is the link

```
http://nex-3.com/posts/3-scribble
```

Is this a gem and how can i install it ? Does it run on Ruby193/Windows7 ?
Please share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you linked says:

> You can download and run Scribble right now from it’s Subversiony home. This home is currently on Hampton Catlin’s server, because mine doesn’t support Subversion.
>
> ```
> svn co svn://hamptoncatlin.com/scribble/trunk scribble
> ```
>
> To run it, just run the `bin/scribble` file. It requires Ruby, of course, as well as the latest Ruby GTK+ bindings and Ruby Cairo bindings (and of course GTK and Cairo themselves). Note that this won’t work with the latest RubyGems – you actually need to compile the latest development versions of these yourself. If you’ve got all of those, it should be able to run on OSX, Linux, and Windows.

Unfortunately, though, the SVN server seems to have disappeared sometime around 2010.  There seems to be a fork of the code at [https://code.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/scribble/trunk](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Evcs-imports/scribble/trunk) , but i haven't even looked at the code, much less tried to use it.  You'll likely need a Bazaar client (`bzr`) to get it...at which point the rest of the instructions would apply.